# Modify regex to include hyphenated words

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I have this tokenizer I found on another stack question, however, I need to modify it and am struggling. It currently splits hyphenated words into separate tokens but I want them to be single tokens.

tokenizer:

```
[(m.start(0), m.end(0),m.group()) for m in re.finditer("\w+|\$[\d\.]+|\S+",target_sentence)]
```

given the following sentence: "half-life is a single token" it should give the following tokens (plus the character offset info):

```
['half-life', 'is', 'a', 'single', 'token']
```

Instead it gives:

```
[(0, 4, 'half'),
(4, 9, '-life'),
(10, 12, 'is'),
(13, 14, 'a'),
(15, 21, 'single'),
(22, 27, 'token')]
```

EDIT: I want the character info not just word tokens so string.split is not going to cut it

Comment: What helps a lot is using an online regex debugging tool and/or python's debug regex flag

Comment: What's wrong with just using `print("half-life is a single token".split())`? There's no point in using `\w+|\$[\d\.]+` if you add the option of `\S+`. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is matching `half` using `\w+` and matching remaining `-life` using last alternate `\S+`.

You may use this regex to capture optional hyphenated words:

```
\w+(?:-\w+)*|\$[\d.]+|\S+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tVpbYc/1)

`\w(?:-\w+)*` will match 1 or more words separated by hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
[m.group() for m in re.finditer("[\w-]+|\$[\d\.-]+|\S+",target_sentence)]
>> ['half-life', 'is', 'a', 'single', 'token']
```

- Only have the code return m.group() instead of the matching indices
- include `-` characters in the character classes